# Simple outer-join like gremlin query not returning any results

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, datastax-enterprise-graph

I wrote the simple query below to traversal between Person to Country but it’s not returning any results.

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").as("p").out("from").hasLabel("Country").as("c").select("p", "c")
```

In the actual data, only `Person` vertices exists and no `Country` vertices or `from` edges exist. I expected to at least return `p` - basically I want to do a left outer join. **However, if I have `Country` and `from` data as well, the query returns results**.

I tried another query using `match` as well but still no results unless there are actual data:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").has("name","bob").match(__.as("p").out("from").hasLabel("Country").as("c")).select("p", "c")
```

I'm running these queries against Datastax Enterpise Graph.

Any idea why it’s returning no results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result you are getting is expected. If there are no "from" edges then the traverser essentially dies and does not proceed any further. Perhaps you could consider using `project()`:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").
  project('name','country').
    by('name')
    by(out('from').hasLabel('Country').values('name').fold())
```

With the "modern" toy graph in TinkerPop, the output looks like this:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').project('name','knows').by().by(out('knows').values('name').fold())
==>[name:v[1],knows:[vadas,josh]]
==>[name:v[2],knows:[]]
==>[name:v[4],knows:[]]
==>[name:v[6],knows:[]]
```

In the future, when you submit questions about Gremlin, please include a Gremlin script that can be pasted into a Gremlin Console which makes it easier to try to more directly answer your specific question.

Comment: Thanks. Will include a Gremlin script next time.